# How to create merge pull request from Bitbucket of one branch to master branch in GitHub

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

How to create merge pull request from Bitbucket to github master branch.

how to set origin and  remote, from Bibucket master brnach want to merge into repositories in github master.
thanks

As suggested cloned both the repositories Bitbucket master and  github master

```
[user@ip-***** ~]$ cd github_clone_copied
[user@ip-*****] github_clone_copied]$ ls -lrth
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  7 user user  73 Nov 16 11:22 web
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user  36 Nov 16 11:23 java
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user  54 Nov 16 11:24 out
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user  55 Nov 16 11:25 python
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user 151 Nov 16 11:26 service
drwxrwxr-x 15 user user 217 Nov 16 11:27 docker
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 255 Nov 16 11:28 lib
[user@ip-********]github_clone_copied]$ pwd
/home/user/github_clone_copied
[user@ip-******** github_clone_copied]$ cd ..
[user@ip-******* ~]$ cd bitbucket_clone_copied/
[user@ip-******* bitbucket_clone_copied]$ ls -lrth
total 4.0K
drwxrwxr-x 14 user user  217 Nov 16 11:42 web
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user  103 Nov 16 11:42 java
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user   54 Nov 16 11:44 out
drwxrwxr-x  6 user user   60 Nov 16 11:45 web
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user   55 Nov 16 11:46 python
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4.0K Nov 16 11:47 lib
drwxrwxr-x  7 user user  151 Nov 16 11:48 service
```

Comment: Your question is quite broad and involves several steps. Where are you running into trouble? You should revise to ask something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation isn't entirely clear, but copy-paste is probably the simplest approach. I don't know of a way to move code between two different repositories using only Git mechanisms. Here's the general idea:

1. Clone the repo from Bitbucket to a local machine
2. Clone the repo from GitHub to the same local machine
3. Copy files from the former to the latter
4. Commit the changes on a working branch and push to GitHub
5. Create the pull request to master there

If the repos are actually clones (or extremely similar), you may be able to configure multiple remotes and pull-push directly. [More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations).